# Getting total count of JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

Can this be done quickly in jQuery before I start looping through them?  Or would I need to also setup a separate group in the response of data with the total count as lets say.. the first variable?

The common response looks something like this:

```
 [
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
 ]
```

But would I use jQuery to return `2` as the total count (before I loop through them all?) Or would I need to do something like this?

```
 [
   {"total":"2"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
 ]
```

Whats the most efficient/common (optimization-wise) way of doing this?

Comment: If it's inside a variable `data`, you can always access it's length using `data.length`

Comment: So I wouldn't need to return the total in the response?  Can you post an answer with a more elaborate answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As after json decoding you are getting an array of objects(from what you have posted). You can always access the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of that to get total count.

As you have got this array, I assume you have been able to parse the json response into a JS object. You can use `dataType: 'json'` to tell jQuery to do that automatically for you or you can parse that yourself using [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) but that is necessary if you set `dataType:'json'` or set `content-Type` header to `application/json` from server.

So you can do something like this

```
$.ajax({
      ....
      dataType: 'json',
      success(function(data){
         if(data){
          var total = data.length; 
         }
      }
 });
```

So you dont need to send the `total count` back from server. You can get that with JS after getting the response and that will make it easier for you traverse that response using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) as the whole array contains same type of objects (doesn't have any special `{"total":"2"}` member).

**Note:** The `length` property is Pure vanilla JS, it has nothing to do with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you don't manipulate JSON (which is a data exchange standard) but javascript objects.

You usually get this object using

```
var data = JSON.parse(mystring)
```

or simply because your `data` is the argument of the success function of a jquery ajax call :

```
   $.ajax(
      ....
      dataType:'json',
      success(function(data){
      })
```

Once parsed, what you have is a javascript object.

In your case it's an array, so you can do standard manipulations :

```
var length = data.length;
var secondObject = data[1];
var firstObjectName = data[0].name;
///etc.
```

Comment: well I guess I might be being pedantic, but I don't think of json as an encoding format. I regard stuff like ascii, utf-8 as encoding formats. JSON is more like a CSV file, so yeah data exchange is better imho